# Populate in Mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to perform associations by referencing method. There are 2 models:
1. User
2. Product

I have established one-to-one relationship of 1 user can have multiple products. User creation is successful
Product creation is successful

**Code Inputs**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/product_demo_x9");
```

Product Schema

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category : String,
  Brand: String
});
var Product = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);
```

User Schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: String,
name: String,
products: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Product"
  }
]
});`
var User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

User Creation

```
User.create({
  email: "madhur@google.com",
  name: "Maddy"
},function(err,newUser){
    if(err){
       console.log(err);
    }
    else {
       console.log(newUser);
    }
});
```

Product Creation

```
Product.create({
    category: "Smartwatches",
    Brand: "Samsung and Google"
}, 
function(err,product){
    console.log(product);
    User.findOne({name : "Maddy"},function(err,foundUser){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            foundUser.products.push(product);
            foundUser.save(function(err,updatedUser){
                if(err){
                     console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                        console.log(updatedUser);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
});
```

Display of associated Data on the console

```
User.find({email: "madhur@google.com"}).
populate("products").
exec(function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(user);
    }
});
```

**Code Outputs**

User Creation (Success)

```
[{
  products: [],
  _id: 5a47acb0317d4e3c2081b8ce,
  email: 'madhur@google.com',
  name: 'Maddy',
  __v: 0
}]
```

Product Creation and associating (Success)

```
{
  _id: 5a47acd53c771123b4018ff1,
  category: 'Smartwatches_2',
  Brand: 'Samsung and Google',
  __v: 0
}
{
  products: [ 5a47acd53c771123b4018ff1 ],
  _id: 5a47acb0317d4e3c2081b8ce,
  email: 'madhur@google.com',
  name: 'Maddy',
  __v: 1
}
```

Display of embedded data  using populate - Failure!!

```
{ MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "products".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError
```

Can anyone please explain me how to do it correctly? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: use Mongoose auto populate plugin , it is easy to use , https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Can you code how to implement autopopulate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
Did the following

1. Downgraded my Mongoose version from 5.00x to 4.10.8 using the following command `npm remove mongoose` then `npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save`
2. Made the following change in app.js file

   ```
   var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email: String,
   name: String,
   products: [
     {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "product" //<---- changed 'Product' to 'product'
     }
   ]
   });`
   var User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
   ```

Thanks to the Stack community for giving a try!

Answer (score 1):

### **Model Name is Case-sensitive**

`'Product'` is not equal to `'product'`
and when u create a model as `'product'` (singular) it converts it into plural, i.e. `'products'`, this is default mongoose behavior, can be overridden.

so change the following:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: String,
name: String,
products: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "products" //<---- changed 'Product' to 'products'
  }
]
});`
var User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/product_demo_x9');

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: String,
    Brand: String
});
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: String,
name: String,
products: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }
]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.create({
    email: 'madhur@google.com',
    name: 'Maddy'
}, function(err, newUser) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(newUser);
    }
});

Product.create({
        category: 'Smartwatches',
        Brand: 'Samsung and Google'
    },
    function(err, product) {
        console.log(product);
        User.findOne({name: 'Maddy'}, function(err, foundUser) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                foundUser.products.push(product);
                foundUser.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(updatedUser);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

User.find({email: 'madhur@google.com'})
    .populate('products')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(user);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Isnt it ref: "MODELNAME".  Here the model name is Product. Anycase, what do you suggest I should put in front of ref: ?

Comment: Try changing both of them with the same case

Comment: Vaikala , yes still no success

Comment: Is the error the same? That code works for me. Then it could be that Product model is not loaded while you are trying to populate.